# Error with bits/pthreadtypes.h while compiling an openmp program

Tags: gcc, openmp

I am working on a project which uses mpi and openmp. I am trying to compile an openmp program and I get the following error :

```
(file /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h, line 69, column 6):
        syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting IDENTIFIER or '(' or '*' or ':'
(/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/pthreadtypes.h, line 69)
        was expecting a declarator here.
```

Can you help with that? Do you know a solution? Can you explain what might be wrong?
Thx

Comment: It's the proper version for your hardware?

Comment: I don't think it's a hardware related problem. About my OS, I have tried it in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Dedian Wheezy.

Comment: What does line 69 of pthreadtypes.h look like? What does the pre-processed file look like (compile with -E)? The compiler is telling you where things are going wrong, so look at where it's pointing!

Comment: There is no problem with the pthreadtypes.h file (it comes along with the packages installed by build-essential) and I can't show you what the pre-processed file looks like because it is over 400 files!